# Logstash _grokparsefailure

Tags: logstash, grok

Would someone be able to add some clarity please?  My grok pattern works fine when I test it against grokdebug and grokconstructor, but then I put it in Logastash it fails from the beginning.  Any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Below is my filter and example log entry.

```
{"casename":"null","username":"null","startdate":"2015-05-26T01:09:23Z","enddate":"2015-05-26T01:09:23Z","time":"0.0156249","methodname":"null","url":"http://null.domain.com/null.php/null/jobs/_search?q=jobid:\"0\"&size=100&from=0","errortype":"null","errorinfo":"null","postdata":"null","methodtype":"null","servername":"null","gaggleid":"a51b90d6-1f82-46a7-adb9-9648def879c5","date":"2015-05-26T01:09:23Z","firstname":"null","lastname":"null"}


filter {
  if [type] == 'EventLog' {
    grok {
      match => { 'message' =>  ' \{"casename":"%{WORD:casename}","username":"%{WORD:username}","startdate":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:startdate}","enddate":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:enddate}","time":"%{NUMBER:time}","methodname":"%{WORD:methodname}","url":"%{GREEDYDATA:url}","errortype":"%{WORD:errortype}","errorinfo":"%{WORD:errorinfo}","postdata":"%{GREEDYDATA:postdata}","methodtype":"%{WORD:methodtype}","servername":"%{HOST:servername}","gaggleid":"%{GREEDYDATA:gaggleid}","date":"%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:date}","firstname":"%{WORD:firstname}","lastname":"%{WORD:lastname}"\} '
     }
   }
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Fails from the beginning", indeed!  See this?

```
'message' =>  ' \{"casename"

              ^^^
```

There's no initial (or trailing) space in your input, but you have them in your pattern.  Remove them, and it works fine in logstash.

BTW, have you seen the json [codec](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-codecs-json.html) or [filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-json.html)?

Comment: Thank you some much.  I was having many issues with everything between the ' ' that I didn't even notice. **THANK YOU**